# Find lowest value with conditions in CLIPS

Tags: search, compare, conditional-statements, clips

I am making a CLIPS program where I have:

**Hotel facts**: (hotel hotelname city stars)

**Country facts**, where all cities belonging to a country appear: (pais countryname city1 city2....)

**Price facts**: (precio  hotelname  kindofroom  price  availablerooms)

The thing is, I need to find the cheapest hotel according to some characteristics, for example, lets assume that I have this initial facts:

```
(deffacts condiciones-iniciales
(hotel RiuTaino PuntaCana 5 )
(hotel RiuFelicidad PuntaCana 4)
(hotel RiuMaracana PuntaCana 4 )
(hotel RiuMaracana2 Baradero 4 )
(hotel RiuRon Baradero 4 )
(hotel RiuMaya RivieraMaya 4 )
(hotel RiuMojito RivieraMaya 4 )
(hotel RiuTequila RivieraMaya 5 )
(hotel RiuSalvaje ElCarmen 4 )
(hotel RiuMontana ElCarmen 4 )
(hotel RiuSantuario ElCarmen 5 )
(pais Rep_Dominicana PuntaCana Baradero SantoDomingo )
(pais Mejico ELCarmen RivieraMaya Cancun)
(precio RiuTaino suite 500 3)
(precio RiuTaino standar 200 20)
(precio RiuFelicidad suite 400 2)
(precio RiuFelicidad standar 100 0)
(precio RiuMaracana suite 600 0)
(precio RiuMaracana standar 300 22)
(precio RiuMaracana2 suite 650 1)
(precio RiuMaracana2 standar 350 2)
(precio RiuRon suite 900 6)
(precio RiuRon standar 700 18)
(precio RiuMaya suite 900 16)
(precio RiuMaya standar 700 88)
(precio RiuMojito suite 550 7)
(precio RiuMojito standar 170 0)
(precio RiuTequila suite 400 3)
(precio RiuTequila standar 350 2)
)
```

and for example, I want to find the cheapest hotel of Rep_Dominicana (any city) of 4 stars which has standar rooms and available rooms. To find hotels that match those characteristics, I did:

```
(defrule busca-hoteles
(hotel ?hotel ?ciudad ?estrellas)
(pais Rep_Dominicana $? ?ciudad $?)
(test (= ?estrellas 4))
(precio ?hotel standar ? ?habitaciones)
(test (> ?habitaciones 0))
=>
(printout t ?hotel crlf)
)
```

but, what can I do to find the cheapest one among the ones that fill those requirements? I am totally lost there. Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can modify the rule to find the cheapest room:

```
(defrule busca-hoteles

   ;; The city is in the dominica republic

   (pais Rep_Dominicana $? ?ciudad $?)

   ;; The hotel is in the city and 4 stars

   (hotel ?hotel ?ciudad 4)

   ;; There are available standard rooms in the hotel

   (precio ?hotel standar ?price ?habitaciones)
   (test (> ?habitaciones 0))

   ;; There are no other 4 star hotel in the same
   ;; city with available standard rooms and a
   ;; lower price

   (not (and (hotel ?hotel2 ?ciudad 4)
             (precio ?hotel2 standar ?price2 ?habitaciones2)
             (test (> ?habitaciones2 0))
             (test (< ?price2 ?price))))

   =>

   (printout t "Cheapest 4 star hotel in " ?ciudad " is " 
               ?hotel " at " ?price crlf))
```